# Use four percentages to get one number

Tags: arithmetic, ratio

Say in Alaska 37% of the people prefer Mountdew, 48% likes Fanta and 6% likes Cola and 9% likes something else.

In Alabama 1% of the people prefer Mountdew, 10% likes Fanta and 82% likes Cola and 7% likes something else.

So people in Alabama are more biased towards one kind of drink, than the people in Alaska, how can I use the four percentages to get one number that represents the biasedness? Is there a formula to calculate this?

I'm trying to make a Choropleth map that shows the biasedness, of each state. The Choropleth map will have ten levels.

[image]

I apologize in advance incase I'm using the wrong tag. I have no idea what tag to put on this question.

**Edit**

I got so far the following formula: `((A - B) / 10) + ((B - C) / 20) + (C - D) / 40`.
 `A, B, C, D` should be assigned in decending order respectively, `A` being the largest number, `D` being the smallest.

Comment: Why is Alaska more biased towards one kind of drink? How would unbiased/completely biased responses look like?

Comment: @Roland Alabama is more biased towards one kind of drink, as 82% of it's people like Cola. Whereas in Alaska it's a bit more moderate since it has two drink which are liked, 37% there likes Mountdew and 48% likes Fanta. So biasedness towards one drink is less in Alaska compared to Alabama.

Comment: So a completely biased survey would be 100% for one drink? And a completely unbiased response would be 1/n, where n is the total number of drinks? Is this the same survey for all states (are all of the drinks a valid answer in every state)?

Comment: @Roland yes that's correct.

Comment: @Do0msDay this isn't going to be an arithmetic problem.  I'd suggest it may fall into #distributions.

Comment: @Do0msDay If you have two categories - A and B, and A = 68% of votes and B has the remaining 32% of votes how would you quantify the bias in this case? (this question is intended to get you think about how to identify and quantify the problem)

Comment: The solution will depend on perconal choice. E.g. what's more biased? 1 ,1 ,49 , 49 or 10, 10, 10, 70? First series has higher % difference but shared #1, second has lower % difference, but higher numeric difference and only 1 #1.

Comment: @DWD Then C and D should be 0%. Which would make the bias somewhat higher. There would be no bias if for example A, B, C, D all were 25% this would mean that there is 0 bias. –

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for the standard deviation?

Or the Mean-Squares error for assuming a flat deviation.

In any case, I assume that the math works out to averaging, for Alaska: (37-25)^2 + (48-25)^2 + (6-25)^2 + (9-25)^2; for Alabama: (1-25)^2 + (10-25)^2 + (82-25)^2 + (7-25)^2

(Of courae, this is treating "other" as an equal choice to Fanta, Coke and Mountain Dew)